# Prediction using a ns spline fit (glmer with ns spline)

Tags: r, predict, spline, mixed-models

I am using the `glmer()` function to determine whether invasive earthworm species weights have significant impacts on 4 different tree species in Minnesota. I am trying to predict the probability of events (because it's logistic regression/ whether tree species will survive or not) at a certain earthworm weight after adjusting other variables. We are also thinking of using odds ratio to compare whether there is a difference among different tree species. So I want to use the `predict()` function to specify a certain weight value and predict the probability of events.

Here is the `summary(data)`. We are specifically looking at `meanwormwt` (average worm weight). What I ultimately want is to predict the probability of events given a certain mean worm weight value. For example, "what's the probability of the event when the mean worm weight is 0.3246?"

```
Exclose        DensF       Species       Park       Parkclust       ParkPlot   
 No :2015   Min.   : 8.00   ACSA:1011   BRSP:672   BRSP1  : 168   BRSP11 :  96  
 Yes:2016   1st Qu.:28.00   QUMA:1004   CSP :672   BRSP2  : 168   BRSP2  :  96  
            Median :48.00   RHCA:1009   GLSP:672   BRSP3  : 168   BRSP6  :  96  
            Mean   :37.52   TIAM:1007   GRF :672   BRSP4  : 168   BRSP8  :  96  
            3rd Qu.:48.00               NLP :671   CAM1   : 168   CSP10  :  96  
            Max.   :48.00               SSP :672   CAM2   : 168   CSP2   :  96  
                                                   (Other):3023   (Other):3455  
     Unique           x               y                PlantId        Cluster   
 BRSP11C:  48   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.000   NLP8C.1.2  :   2   Min.   :1.0  
 BRSP11E:  48   1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:2.000   SSP10E.2.5 :   2   1st Qu.:2.0  
 BRSP2C :  48   Median :3.000   Median :4.000   BRSP10C.1.1:   1   Median :3.0  
 BRSP2E :  48   Mean   :2.976   Mean   :4.142   BRSP10C.1.2:   1   Mean   :2.5  
 BRSP6C :  48   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:6.000   BRSP10C.1.3:   1   3rd Qu.:3.5  
 BRSP6E :  48   Max.   :6.000   Max.   :8.000   BRSP10C.1.4:   1   Max.   :4.0  
 (Other):3743                                   (Other)    :4023                
      Plot           LowLevXBlks   DeerFPP13park   DeerFPP15park     DeerAvgFrac    
 Min.   : 1.000   SSP10E:2 :   9   Min.   : 1.20   Min.   :0.9167   Min.   :0.1654  
 1st Qu.: 4.000   BRSP11C:1:   8   1st Qu.: 1.60   1st Qu.:1.9167   1st Qu.:0.4878  
 Median : 7.000   BRSP11C:2:   8   Median : 1.90   Median :2.4167   Median :0.5365  
 Mean   : 6.392   BRSP11C:3:   8   Mean   : 8.13   Mean   :2.3194   Mean   :0.5420  
 3rd Qu.: 9.500   BRSP11C:4:   8   3rd Qu.:12.80   3rd Qu.:3.0000   3rd Qu.:0.6673  
 Max.   :12.000   BRSP11C:5:   8   Max.   :20.90   Max.   :3.3333   Max.   :0.8500  
                  (Other)  :3982                                                    
 DeerFPP13plot   DeerFPP15plot    Lt15CnpyOpen    Lt13CnpyOpen      pHH2013    
 Min.   : 0.00   Min.   :0.000   Min.   : 4.04   Min.   : 5.01   Min.   :5.48  
 1st Qu.: 0.00   1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.: 9.81   1st Qu.: 8.79   1st Qu.:6.46  
 Median : 1.00   Median :1.500   Median :13.92   Median :13.73   Median :6.89  
 Mean   : 2.29   Mean   :1.663   Mean   :15.44   Mean   :18.27   Mean   :6.93  
 3rd Qu.: 3.00   3rd Qu.:2.000   3rd Qu.:18.51   3rd Qu.:23.69   3rd Qu.:7.48  
 Max.   :11.00   Max.   :7.000   Max.   :58.81   Max.   :57.38   Max.   :8.17  
                                 NA's   :96                                    
    worm16ct       worm16wt        meanwormct      meanwormwt       PlotMoist     
 Min.   : 0.0   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   : 0.00   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.1206  
 1st Qu.:10.0   1st Qu.:0.2729   1st Qu.:13.00   1st Qu.:0.3246   1st Qu.:0.1622  
 Median :22.0   Median :0.6463   Median :23.33   Median :0.6292   Median :0.1873  
 Mean   :26.5   Mean   :1.1226   Mean   :27.92   Mean   :0.9185   Mean   :0.1948  
 3rd Qu.:37.0   3rd Qu.:1.2940   3rd Qu.:40.00   3rd Qu.:1.0901   3rd Qu.:0.2239  
 Max.   :94.0   Max.   :7.5096   Max.   :85.33   Max.   :3.6966   Max.   :0.2927  
 NA's   :96     NA's   :96                                                        
   ClustMoist         AvgJJA          AvgDJF          TotalBA             FireObsF   
 Min.   :0.1366   Min.   :18.90   Min.   :-9.300   Min.   :0.4269   FireObs   :  96  
 1st Qu.:0.1710   1st Qu.:20.90   1st Qu.:-7.200   1st Qu.:1.1455   NotFireObs:3935  
 Median :0.1883   Median :21.30   Median :-6.600   Median :1.4635                    
 Mean   :0.1966   Mean   :21.28   Mean   :-6.688   Mean   :1.5469                    
 3rd Qu.:0.2190   3rd Qu.:21.80   3rd Qu.:-6.300   3rd Qu.:1.9987                    
 Max.   :0.2735   Max.   :24.50   Max.   :-4.700   Max.   :2.7619                    

   Alive12Sum     Alive12SumF  Alive16JuneF  Alive16June    
 Min.   :0.0000   Alive:3927   Alive:1556   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:1.0000   Dead : 104   Dead :2379   1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :1.0000                NA's :  96   Median :0.0000  
 Mean   :0.9742                             Mean   :0.3954  
 3rd Qu.:1.0000                             3rd Qu.:1.0000  
 Max.   :1.0000                             Max.   :1.0000  
                                            NA's   :96
```

I used ns spline on mean earthworm weight and divided into 3 splines. What codes do I need to use for this? I've tried to use predict.ns or predict.merMod but I don't know how to since we are not looking for just overall average predict value.. We want to look at predict value at certain weight. What commands should I try? What should I do?

Here is my glmer code:

````
```{r}
nsglm<-glmer(Mort16JuneAPF ~ Exclose*Species + ns(meanwormwt, df=3, knots=c(0.3246,1.0901))*Species + (1 | Park) + (1 | Cluster:Park) + (1 | Plot:Cluster:Park) + (1|Exclose:ParkPlot) + (1 | x:Unique), data = mydata, family = binomial, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", calc.derivs = FALSE))
summary(nsglm)
```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Mort16JuneAPF ~ Exclose * Species + ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246,  
    1.0901)) * Species + (1 | Park) + (1 | Cluster:Park) + (1 |  
    Plot:Cluster:Park) + (1 | Exclose:ParkPlot) + (1 | x:Unique)
   Data: mydata
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", calc.derivs = FALSE)

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4253.3   4410.2  -2101.7   4203.3     3910 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2758 -0.6492  0.2821  0.6346  4.0010 

Random effects:
 Groups            Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 x:Unique          (Intercept) 0.01345  0.1160  
 Exclose:ParkPlot  (Intercept) 0.51799  0.7197  
 Plot:Cluster:Park (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
 Cluster:Park      (Intercept) 0.28753  0.5362  
 Park              (Intercept) 0.03863  0.1965  
Number of obs: 3935, groups:  
x:Unique, 564; Exclose:ParkPlot, 142; Plot:Cluster:Park, 71; Cluster:Park, 24; Park, 6

Fixed effects:
                                                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                                      0.6957     0.4435   1.569 0.116746    
ExcloseYes                                                      -2.7133     0.2090 -12.981  < 2e-16 ***
SpeciesQUMA                                                      1.2551     0.3827   3.279 0.001041 ** 
SpeciesRHCA                                                     -0.6303     0.3407  -1.850 0.064331 .  
SpeciesTIAM                                                     -0.5476     0.3500  -1.565 0.117687    
ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))1               1.2171     0.6496   1.874 0.060986 .  
ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))2               0.8967     0.9645   0.930 0.352534    
ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))3              -0.2013     0.7047  -0.286 0.775132    
ExcloseYes:SpeciesQUMA                                           1.5177     0.2375   6.391 1.65e-10 ***
ExcloseYes:SpeciesRHCA                                           2.2524     0.2138  10.533  < 2e-16 ***
ExcloseYes:SpeciesTIAM                                           1.0164     0.2295   4.430 9.44e-06 ***
SpeciesQUMA:ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))1  -0.3065     0.6130  -0.500 0.617043    
SpeciesRHCA:ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))1  -1.0661     0.5614  -1.899 0.057555 .  
SpeciesTIAM:ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))1   0.6600     0.6074   1.087 0.277240    
SpeciesQUMA:ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))2  -2.1818     0.8225  -2.653 0.007984 ** 
SpeciesRHCA:ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))2  -1.3299     0.7390  -1.800 0.071897 .  
SpeciesTIAM:ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))2   3.0146     0.7774   3.878 0.000105 ***
SpeciesQUMA:ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))3  -2.8120     0.5579  -5.041 4.64e-07 ***
SpeciesRHCA:ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))3  -0.4749     0.5100  -0.931 0.351807    
SpeciesTIAM:ns(meanwormwt, df = 3, knots = c(0.3246, 1.0901))3   2.4477     0.5762   4.248 2.16e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
````

Comment: I don't understand the question. What weight are you referring to? Model weights? You can't "predict at a certain weight". I don't see weight as an effect anywhere in the model.

Comment: Better place to go when presenting a methods-oriented question without data (in the context of admitted user confusion) would be the R Mixed Models mailing list.

Comment: I added my data. So there is a variable called meanwormwt which indicates mean earthworm weight. What I want to predict is the probability of events (whether earthworm weight impacts on the tree species survival rates given certain values of the earthworm weight) so for example) what's probability of the tree species survive given the worm weight is 0.03? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `predict()` with the `newdata` argument. You need to specify *some* value for every fixed-effect input variable, e.g.

```
nd <- with(mydata,
   expand.grid(Exclose=levels(Exclose), Species=levels(Species))
nd$meanwormwt <- 0.361
predict(nsglm, re.form=~0, newdata=nd)
```

`re.form=~0` specifies  that you want to make population-level predictions (i.e., for a new/unknown value of the random effects grouping factors).